# D3js line chart error "attribute d: Expected number, "M49,NaNZ"."

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I am trying to get a line chart using d3js chart. Below is the code. This is the following error I get "attribute d: Expected number, "M49,NaNZ"."I am parsing the x axis as name and y as counts. It seems like there is something wrong in the code while plotting the line path which is not getting the data as numbers.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



var x =  d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.name);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.count);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [{
                "name": "Seasonal Pop",
                "code": "SEASONAL_POP",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
                    "count": 1200
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
                    "count": 2000
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
                    "count": 1060
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
                    "count": 2300
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
                    "count": 1300
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
                    "count": 3400
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
                    "count": 4500
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
                    "count": 5500
                }]
            }];

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.name = +d.date ;
    d.count = +d.count;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.name;
    }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.count;
    })]);

svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
.attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
.attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
.attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are accessing your data incorrectly. Your data is an array with one element. That one element contains an object with `name`, `code`, and `children`. So when you just pass the whole object to `valueline()` it's not going to work because `valueline` is then going to look for values that don't exist.

Also it looks like you are trying to access a `date` attribute that doesn't exist with `d.name = +d.date`

The data you really want to plot is in `data[0].children`. I've set the x-axis domain from the data, but if you want to control the order of an ordinal scale, it's often better to explicitly set the domain with something like `x.domain(['SEASONAL_CYQ3', 'SEASONAL_CYQ4',...])`

Here's a working example. It need a little stylizing, but I've started some text styling on the axes to get it started.

Also, it's worth upgrading to use d3 v4 if your just getting started with it.

```js
   var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 50
};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



var x =  d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.name);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.count);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var data = [{
                "name": "Seasonal Pop",
                "code": "SEASONAL_POP",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
                    "count": 1200
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
                    "count": 2000
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
                    "count": 1060
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
                    "count": 2300
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
                    "count": 1300
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
                    "count": 3400
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
                    "count": 4500
                }, {
                    "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
                    "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
                    "count": 5500
                }]
            }];

x.domain(data[0].children.map(d => d.name))
y.domain([0, d3.max(data[0].children, function (d) {
    return d.count;
    })]);

console.log("xed", x(data[0].children[0].name))


svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
.attr("d", valueline(data[0].children))

svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
.attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr('font-size', '10px')
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");

svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
.attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('font-size', '10px')
```

```css
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```